# The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, firebird, filepath, ioexception

I am new in C# and I have a problem connecting to a Firebird database. I want my program to access a Firebird Database [FDB format file]. I have problem, see the code below:

```
File.Copy(pathway, new_pathway, true);

FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection("User=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database= " + new_pathway +
    ";DataSource=localhost;" );
string SQLCOMMAND = " SELECT UOM FROM ST_ITEM_UOM WHERE CODE = 'ANT'";

addDetailsConnection.Open();
FbCommand readCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCOMMAND, addDetailsConnection);

FbDataReader myreader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myreader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(myreader[0].ToString());
}
myreader.Close();
readCommand.Dispose();
addDetailsConnection.Close();
addDetailsConnection.Dispose();
```

This code lets me read my FDB file and extract the data. When the code executes for the first time, there is no error or problem, However when when I execute it again, this error is shown:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ACC-0001.FDB' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Well, obviously the file is in use. Have you tried figuring out which program it is that is using it?

Comment: Ya true the file is in used and I noe it but the File is being used by the program itself. Add on I had constantly check on the file status and  obviously that the file is being used after i execute the addDetailsCOnnection.Open()

Comment: Add on, I check many time and I had try both Close and Dispose function to drop the connection and the connection status already in "Close" status but the file are still in access ToT

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why is the file in use by your program? It should only be in use by the Firebird server (as you are not using embedded). Depending on the exact Firebird architecture installed, the Firebird server needs exclusive access (SuperServer), or can work with shared access (Classic and SuperClassic).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to check which program is locking the file. It might be caused by your code or by another process running on your machine.

The tool identifies the process, for example:

> C:>handle.exe c:\test.xlsx
>
> Handle v3.46 Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals -
>   www.sysinternals.com
>
> EXCEL.EXE          pid: 3596   type: File           414: C:\test.xlsx

As found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/074baf4f-1040-43f8-9980-60f273967d8d/which-process-is-locking-a-file).

If the problem lies within your code, make sure you dispose and close all connections, preferably by using them within `using` sections:

```
using (FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection("...")) 
{
    // do work
}
```

More details on using `using` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Hmm somehow I had try the following code
                  myreader.Close();
                   readCommand.Dispose();
                 addDetailsConnection.Close();
                  addDetailsConnection.Dispose();
To close all of the connection but the file is in used :(

Comment: @MathewSee, as suggested, try _using_ the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

You might have bumped into this Firebird issue: [FB server reports that DB file is used by another application on secondary attachment attempt through a symlink](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3558)

It only happens on Windows and only when two non-embedded connections use different path names of which one or both have a symlink in their path so they effectively point to the same location.

Both `handle.exe` and `Process Explorer` will only show the canonical (final) filename that `fbserver.exe` actually opens.

The only way to find out is to:

1. compare connection strings.
2. verify with `handle.exe` or `Process Explorer` that the files are indeed opened by `fbserver.exe` (and not by your process itself using an embedded connection)